# Should I consider XMPP for any chat app

Tags: android, iphone, xmpp, chat, real-time-updates

For a chat app, with **extended features** (not related to chat but realtime data) with support for `Websocket` and `SocketIO` based server, do I really need to integrate or consider `XMPP`. Isn't XMPP overkill for a simple file sharing (S3 storage), chat and other data communication (server status etc).

In my application, custom data is fetched from different storage, need to push to `Message Queue` in some event, and store uploaded file in S3. All these are not XMPP supported, So anyhow I will have to customize XMPP server implementations a lot if I choose it as backend.

Do you think I would be better off implementing all these by my own, compleletly skipping XMPP.
Or, is there anything in XMPP which I may have missed for considering it.

Support required in app:

1. Websocket
2. Long polling ajax
3. S3 storage
4. Redis / Aerospike DB
5. REST call to other services hosted on different machines
6. Android Client
7. iOS client
8. Windows client based on Qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMPP, formerly Jabber, is based on XML. I'm an old hand with XML, yet even I can see that it was chatty and redundant in creating open and close element tags, and also required a heck of a lot of open and close quotes.

What seems to be far more popular these days, especially in the NoSQL arena, are syntactically terser codifications of data such as JSON, or BSON (Binary JSON).

JSON: http://www.json.org/
Binary JSON: http://bsonspec.org/

Is there something specific in the schema, syntax, parsing or web-baed reification of XML which is a reason you want to use XMPP? Otherwise, you might find JSON an easier and more efficient way to encode data.

Also let me know if this answer was useful.

Comment: I made this answer back in Nov 2014. What did you decide to do? What's the status of your project now? Let me know!

Comment: I choose Websocket with Redis, Python (Tornado), Mongo and all custom implementation. I could have used XMPP with ejabberd, but that require me to learn Erlang (i couldn't digest that language). Simply using ejabberd/xmpp will get my chat application online, but I have to implement my authentication, storage, integration with main app and many needed functionality. The data transfer is in JSON. Its working pretty stable apart from few issues with Chrome.

Comment: Cool! Glad you're up and running. Just give a shout-out if you need Aerospike to help scale. Otherwise you look like you're well on your way. Best wishes! -Pete.